# AS3 find half of getTimer to allow secondary loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have it set up so I can hit spacebar twice to set a timer duration to repeat a movie clip.. I want to repeat a second movie clip at half the duration of the other. so for every loop it loops twice. Here's what I've tried:

```
var timeStart:Number;
var loopDuration:Number;
var timeLastLoop:Number;
var rando80:Number;
var rando802:Number;
var rando8:Number;
var randoy:Number;
var halfduration:Number;
 var randomImage:Bitmap;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);


function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
        if (!timeStart) { // First time SPACE is hit
            timeStart       = getTimer();

        } else { // Second time SPACE is hit
            loopDuration    = getTimer() - timeStart; // set the loop duration
            halfduration    = (getTimer() - timeStart) *.5;
            timeStart       = NaN; // reset the start time
            loop();
        }
    }
}

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    rando8 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
    rando80 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 70);
    randoy = Math.floor(Math.random() * -1000);
    rando802 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 70);

 if ( timeLastLoop && halfduration) {
        if (getTimer() >= timeLastLoop + halfduration) { // if it's time to loop
                circleThump2.gotoAndPlay(1);
        }
 }

    if (loopDuration && timeLastLoop) {
        if (getTimer() >= timeLastLoop + loopDuration) { // if it's time to loop
            loop();
        }

    }

}

function loop():void {
    timeLastLoop      = getTimer();
    circleThump.gotoAndPlay(1);
    MovieClipMan.gotoAndPlay(rando80);
    hotdog.gotoAndPlay(rando80);
    MovieClipMan.y    = randoy;
    MovieClipMan2.gotoAndPlay(rando80);
    movieClipColor.gotoAndStop(rando8);
    MovieClipMan2.y   = randoy;
```

Comment: does it just simply not work or is there a specific problem you need help with?

Comment: yeah the problem is that it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to make it work and if so please tell me what's going on here. Thank you!